# PSD pixels to ios points

Tags: ios, user-interface, photoshop

I received design (photoshop) layout from a designer in pixels. How do I convert those into points as required by iOS?

I tried substituting pixles for points thinking that it may be a `1:1` conversion but on coding in the app the design looks weird (bigger then expected).

Table header height example: Tried converted 32px+40px of psd = 72 points in ios 
but in the comps the table header is just a little bigger than the navBar (which is ofcourse 44 points).

Should the designer be providing the layout in points rather than pixels?

If not then how do I convert the pixels to points for iOS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Converting pixels to points depends on the target iOS device. On a 1x device (iPad 1 & 2, iPhone up to 3GS), 1 UIKit point == 1 pixel. On Retina devices (iPad 3 and up, iPhone 4 and up), 1 UIKit point == 2 pixels.

Comment: On iPhone 6 Plus, 1 UIKit point == 3 of, but then it is scaled down to fit in the display. Detailed explanation here: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified

Comment: The paintcodeapp link is a really good resource to figure out the different resolutions and screen sizes. Any idea what the downsampling is all about?

Comment: A fully 3x display was presumably too expensive, but the 3x math works out well for developers, so they shipped with a 1080p display and then scale in software.

Comment: I have a psd made on 1080x1920 pixels. Have I to divide it on 3 to get the point values?

Comment: No iPhone has a 1080x1920 point screen, so you can’t get it from that. Your design should use one of the point values from here: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions